# SharedPreferences does not store value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am currently working with SharedPreferences in Android, and I encountered a weird behavior I cannot explain. This is my code:

```
SharedPreferences appPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
appPreferences.edit().putBoolean("launched_before", true);
appPreferences.edit().apply();
appPreferences = null;
appPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean test = appPreferences.getBoolean("launched_before", false); //this is false
```

The value that I write to my SharedPreferences is not being saved. I know I could use `getDefaultSharedPreferences()`, but I do not want to do this here, as the default file stores other values.

When I use `commit()` instead of `apply()`, the return value of `commit()` is `true`, but I still cannot load the file correctly.

Comment: I believe applying a SharedPreferences is an asynchronous action, and so you aren't guaranteed a result in your synchronous code. Have you tried getting the boolean after you put it in? I don't see the point of reassignment

Comment: @cricket_007 no matter where I try to read it, it will be false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your code doesn't do what you think. When you call edit(), it does not start an "edit transaction". Instead it returns a new instance of Editor object each time you call it. So let's look at this code:

```
SharedPreferences appPreferences = getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// Here you create a FIRST Editor object, which stores the modification
// You never call apply() on this object, and thus your changes are dropped.
appPreferences.edit().putBoolean("launched_before", true);

// Here you create a SECOND Editor object (which has no modifications)
// and you call apply() on it, thus changing nothing.
appPreferences.edit().apply();
```

You created the first editor object which you put settings in, but you called apply on the **second** editor object which had no changes. Since you never called apply() on the editor object which had modification, your change was never saved.

The fix is obvious - use a single instance of Editor for your modification, and call apply/commit on this instance:

```
SharedPreferences appPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = appPreferences.edit();
ed.putBoolean("launched_before", true);
ed.apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use as key "com.yourdomain.yourapp.your_key_name" and for each value use another key...try this

```
private SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(appContext);

public void putBoolean(String key, boolean value) {
    checkForNullKey(key);
    preferences.edit().putBoolean(key, value).apply();
}

public boolean getBoolean(String key) {
    return preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
}

public void checkForNullKey(String key){
    if (key == null){
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
}
```

Comment: and how is this related to my question? I do not want to use defaultSharedPreferences

Comment: because it will not overwrite your default stored vaule? if i understand what  you need? Each time you use putBoolean("com.blabla.someapp.testBoolean1", true) and putBoolean("..... .testBoolean2, false) it will store for testBoolean1 true and false for testBoolean2...